# How to import a specific folder containing python codes in any directory using conda environment?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I have a folder containing many python codes. I want to use this folder at any directory. How can I do that? I use this command in the directory that it exists:

```
python -c "from myfolder import *"
```

I'm using anaconda and python 2.7. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should be able to fix it by adding your folder to the PYTHONPATH, so by doing:

```py
import sys
sys.path.append("your folder")
```

you should be able to use the scripts of this folder at any directory.
Let me know if it helps :)